# Single text file with multiple tables

Tags: r

I am trying to import data from a single text file that has multiple tables.  The tables vary in length, but have a common speration between each.  The seperation between each table is a number followed by a character.  For example,

```
19,EOP
1,10.,92.9144,202.1271,0,B,10-Dec-2014 11:46

2,5.,0.,153.3754,0.,,10-Dec-2014 11:52

3,5.,20380.8867,162.0626,24555.9395,,10-Dec-2014 11:58

4,5.,21941.2773,197.9289,25361.4414,,10-Dec-2014 12:04

10,EOP
1,0.98,164702.1563,179.828,0,B,10-Dec-2014 09:46

2,1.08,0.,180.6869,0.,,10-Dec-2014 09:48

3,1.07,0.,190.6853,0.,,10-Dec-2014 09:50

4,1.32,0.,163.7527,0.,,10-Dec-2014 09:52

5,1.29,0.,167.3766,0.,,10-Dec-2014 09:54
```

I have been trying to use the read table function, but i cannot seem to use the function to recognize the table indicator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try to use [`read.mtable`](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun/blob/master/R/read.mtable.R) from my GitHub-only ["SOfun" package](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun).

Using the sample data you shared saved in a file called "test.txt" in my present working, directory, I tried the following:

```
library(SOfun) ## Or just copy and paste the function for your session...
read.mtable("test.txt", chunkId = "\\d+,EOP", header = FALSE, sep = ",")
# $`19,EOP`
#   V1 V2         V3       V4       V5 V6                V7
# 1  1 10    92.9144 202.1271     0.00  B 10-Dec-2014 11:46
# 2  2  5     0.0000 153.3754     0.00    10-Dec-2014 11:52
# 3  3  5 20380.8867 162.0626 24555.94    10-Dec-2014 11:58
# 4  4  5 21941.2773 197.9289 25361.44    10-Dec-2014 12:04
# 
# $`10,EOP`
#   V1   V2       V3       V4 V5 V6                V7
# 1  1 0.98 164702.2 179.8280  0  B 10-Dec-2014 09:46
# 2  2 1.08      0.0 180.6869  0    10-Dec-2014 09:48
# 3  3 1.07      0.0 190.6853  0    10-Dec-2014 09:50
# 4  4 1.32      0.0 163.7527  0    10-Dec-2014 09:52
# 5  5 1.29      0.0 167.3766  0    10-Dec-2014 09:54
```

---

As you can see if you view the source, the function is a basic wrapper for `read.table` that has a few other lines to help identify the number of lines to skip with each round of `read.table`.

---

Obviously, change your "chunkID" argument to be representative of what your table names actually are :-)

Comment: That is great, now i have issue of exporting all of this back into multiple text files, so my co workers can use excel to import this data.  I know, i know, EXCEL=gross, but they have yet top be enlightened.

Comment: @MadmanLee, it's a list, so you can just use something like `lapply(your-list, write.csv, otherargumentstowritecsv)`.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this with any of the base R functions i know of. What you can do is read all the data in, then find the break points with a regular expression (or something else) and then parse each chunk. For example

```
lines <- readLines("data.csv")
group <- cumsum(grepl("^\\d+,\\w+$", lines))  #number,character

lapply(split(lines, group), function(x) read.table(text=x[-1], sep=","))
```

to get

```
$`1`
  V1 V2         V3       V4       V5 V6                V7
1  1 10    92.9144 202.1271     0.00  B 10-Dec-2014 11:46
2  2  5     0.0000 153.3754     0.00    10-Dec-2014 11:52
3  3  5 20380.8867 162.0626 24555.94    10-Dec-2014 11:58
4  4  5 21941.2773 197.9289 25361.44    10-Dec-2014 12:04

$`2`
  V1   V2       V3       V4 V5 V6                V7
1  1 0.98 164702.2 179.8280  0  B 10-Dec-2014 09:46
2  2 1.08      0.0 180.6869  0    10-Dec-2014 09:48
3  3 1.07      0.0 190.6853  0    10-Dec-2014 09:50
4  4 1.32      0.0 163.7527  0    10-Dec-2014 09:52
5  5 1.29      0.0 167.3766  0    10-Dec-2014 09:54
```

Comment: Very nice, I was just about to post something similar, using `readChar` instead of `readLines`. +1