# Multiple headers in data file at different row intervals

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a data table but it has multiple headers at different rows (same header on 1st row, 5th row, 12th row) and not at fixed intervals. How do I skip those header rows and create my new data set with just one header? Also it would be helpful if I am able to identify these files and display the files in a separate place.

Comment: I tend to solve such issues outside of R, before loading my dataset, using `sed`. It's also possible to do this with `grep`, `awk` or `perl`. Would this be an option for you? These utitlities are available on UNIX-like systems, OSX and if you're on windows through `cygwin`.

Comment: yes, i'd use `grep`; it is easy enough to solve this problem in R in my opinion. would help if you could show us a sample of your data.

Comment: Check out my `read.mtable` function, as used in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27427531/1270695) perhaps? Each table would then become a list item.

Comment: how about you try something and show effort or at least that you have thought about it

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different options, which is best depends on how often you will do this, the nature of your data, and your skill set with different tools.

One option as has been mentioned in the comments above is to use a seperate program to filter out the extra header rows before reading the file into R.  An extension of this idea is that R has a `pipe` file connection that can be used to run an outside command and then read from the output.  For example you could try something like:

```
mydata <- read.table( pipe('perl -ne "print if /[0-9]/" mydata.txt') )
```

This will run the perl command (you could also use grep or other tools) which will run through the file one line at a time and only pass along those that contain at least one digit (assuming that your header lines don't contain any digits) which are then read by the `read.table` function in R.  You will probably want a little more sophisticated command to preprocess your data.

Another option is to just read in everything, then delete those rows that had the header information.  I would suggest setting `colClasses` when reading in to tell R which columns should be numerical, etc. (otherwise the header information will likely cause R to read everything as a string or factor).  Then when a header row is read in, the numeric columns will instead have NA as the value, then you can quickly find all the rows that have NA in a numeric column and remove those rows (unless you have other NA values that you want to keep).

Another option is to use the `readLines` function to read in your file as character strings, then use R's `grep` or other functions to strip out the header rows and then pass the results to `read.table` or other reading function:

```
mylines <- readLines('mydata.txt')
mylines2 <- mylines[ !grepl('[a-zA-Z]', mylines), ]
mydata <- read.table(text=mylines2)
```

There are probably other options (and the above will need tweaking for your specific case), but this should get you started.